# Layout to stretch component width but let height be decided by what it holds

Tags: java, user-interface, layout-manager, miglayout

I can't seem to find the correct layoutmanager, perhaps it doesn't exist, so I wanted to do it in miglayout, yet I can't seem to find my way to do this there either.

**Most documentation, tutorials and examples I found don't adress the JPanel having contents at all 0.o**

The problem I'm having is, I've got two JPanels(C 1&2) inside a JPanel(B) which in turn is inside a bigger resizeable JPanel(A).
Now both lowest level "C" JPanels contain 5 buttons, when the highest level "A" resizes and gets less width the **buttons** go from this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

As you can see the FlowLayout I'm using on the lowest level "C" JPanels is doing it's job!

```
c.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT,0,0))
```

But while the "B" JPanel that holds the C's does exactly what I want for the horizontal part

```
b.setLayout(new BoxLayout(b, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
```

I don't want it doing that on the height though!

**So could anyone point me in the right direction like a tutorial or docs that cover such stuff? For miglayout or swing layout managers?**

Comment: You never said what resize behavior you actually want, so it's impossible to tell you how to get that. You'll probably want to set some of the inner JPanel's widths to be not resizable.

Comment: @Gene I want the buttons to shift from a horizontal line to a vertical line as the width is resized and at the same time **it'd be nice if the panel containing them to change it's height to fit them.**(the width can stay hooked to the value of it's parent's panel)

Comment: (sorry for the late reply! irl unforeseen circumstance) Oh and thank you so much for editing in those pictures Lucas, very helpful and kind of you!

Comment: I see now.  If you post code for your example I think I can get it working.  The problem is that metrics are computed with respect to `JPanel` contents (like your buttons) only when `pack()` is called. By default this doesn't happen during window resizing. But you should be able to add a window resize event handler that does the job.  Ideally it will sense when the button box orientation has changed and call `pack()` only in that case.  Calling `pack()` once per mouse move event during a resize would be quite expensive.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a solution with a `MigLayout` manager. The panels keep their
height nicely when the window is resized and never shrink below the size
necessary to hold all the buttons.

```
package com.zetcode;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;


public class MigLayoutSolution extends JFrame {

    public MigLayoutSolution() {

        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {

        JPanel pnl = new JPanel(new MigLayout());

        pnl.add(createPanel1("First"), "push, grow, wrap"); 
        pnl.add(createPanel2("Second"), "push, grow");

        add(pnl);
        pack();

        setTitle("MigLayout solution");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
    }

    private JPanel createPanel1(String text) {

        JPanel pnl = new JPanel(new MigLayout());
        pnl.add(new JButton("A"));
        pnl.add(new JButton("B"));
        pnl.add(new JButton("C"));
        pnl.add(new JButton("D"));
        pnl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(text));

        return pnl;
    }    

    private JPanel createPanel2(String text) {

        JPanel pnl = new JPanel(new MigLayout());
        pnl.add(new JButton("E"));
        pnl.add(new JButton("F"));
        pnl.add(new JButton("G"));
        pnl.add(new JButton("H"));
        pnl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(text));

        return pnl;
    }        

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MigLayoutSolution ex = new MigLayoutSolution();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });          
    }
}
```

The first picture shows two panels with plenty of empty space.

[image: MigLayout Solution 1]

The second picture shows the panels in their minimal size.

[image: MigLayout Solution 2]